# Retrieving xpath of the selected text in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I want to retrieve the xpath of the currently selected text in a browser. Using JavaScript I am able to get the selected text, but was not able to get the xpath.

I can find the xpath manually using Firebug, but I want to do it programatically. Is it possible to do it?

[EDIT] Okay, found a pointer to the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214862/equivalent-of-firebugs-copy-xpath-in-internet-explorer). Modified the code from that thread to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the selection spans several DOM elements, what would the path be?

I don't think you can get the selected DOM element from the `getSelection()` (or `document.selected`).

You could try to set up document wide event handlers for `mousedown` and `mouseup`. On `mousedown` you store the element under the pointer and on `mouseup` you check if there is a selection.

The next step would be to generate the path to that element. That is also quite [tricky](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3754).

Comment: "What if the selection spans several DOM elements, what would the path be?" - That's a very good point. I didn't think about it. But as of now, I can assume that the user will only select the text inside a node.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - but by looping through each ancestor using XSL, you can probably build up the XPath.

```
for each ancestor::* { newXPath = concat (local-name(.), [current_node_postion], previousGeneratedXPath)}
```

Recurse through each ancestor and build the complete XPath.