# Finding an elements XPath using IE Developer tool

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, ie-developer-tools

Is there a way to find an element's XPath using IE Developer Tool?

Comment: IE doesn't support XHTML, so I think it's unlikely.

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is to find CSS selectors you can use MRI (once MRI is open, click any element to see various selectors for the element):

http://westciv.com/mri/

For Xpath:

http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2008/12/xpath-in-internet-explorer.html

Answer (score 4):

This post suggests that you should be able to get the IE Developer Toolbar to show you the XPath for an element you click on if you turn on the "select element by click" option.
http://blog.balfes.net/?p=62

Alternatively this post suggests either bookmarklets, or IE debugbar:
[Equivalent of Firebug's "Copy XPath" in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214862/equivalent-of-firebugs-copy-xpath-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Tried both ways , bookmarklet is not working for some reason and I cannot really get a xpath from select element by click option or Debug toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can find/debug XPath/CSS locators in the IE as well as in different browsers with the tool called [SWD Page Recorder](https://github.com/dzhariy/swd-recorder/releases)

The only restrictions/limitations:

1. The browser should be started from the tool
2. [Internet Explorer Driver Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) - `IEDriverServer.exe` - should be downloaded separately and placed near `SwdPageRecorder.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find some work around getting xpath in IE?

There are many add-ons for other browsers like [xpather](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpather/gabekepgockchhemajjahpchlnkadiac/related?hl=en) for **Chrome** or [xpather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/xpather/), [xpath-checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) and firebug for **FireFox** that will give you the xpath of an element in a second. But sadly there is no add-on or tool available that will do this for **IE**. For most cases you can get the xpath of the elements that fall in your script using the above tools in Firefox and tweak them a little (if required) to make them work in IE.

But if you are testing an application that will work only in IE or the specific scenario or page that has this element will open-up/play-out only in IE then you cannot use any of the above mention tools to find the XPATH.
Well the only thing that works in this case is the Bookmarklets that were coded just for this purpose. Bookmarklets are JavaScript code that you will add in IE as bookmarks and later use to get the XPATH of the element you desire. Using these you can get the XPATH as easily as you get using xpather or any other firefox addon.

**STEPS TO INSTALL BOOKMARKLETS**

1)Open IE

2)Type about:blank in the address bar and hit enter

3)From Favorites main menu select ---> Add favorites

4) In the Add a favorite popup window enter name GetXPATH1.

5)Click add button in the add a favorite popup window.

6)Open the Favorites menu and right click the newly added favorite and select properties option.

7)GetXPATH1 Properties will open up. Select the web Document Tab.

8)Enter the following in the URL field.

```
javascript:function getNode(node){var nodeExpr=node.tagName;if(!nodeExpr)return null;if(node.id!=''){nodeExpr+="[@id='"+node.id+"']";return "/"+nodeExpr;}var rank=1;var ps=node.previousSibling;while(ps){if(ps.tagName==node.tagName){rank++;}ps=ps.previousSibling;}if(rank>1){nodeExpr+='['+rank+']';}else{var ns=node.nextSibling;while(ns){if(ns.tagName==node.tagName){nodeExpr+='[1]';break;}ns=ns.nextSibling;}}return nodeExpr;}
```

9)Click Ok. Click YES on the popup alert.

10)Add another favorite by following steps 3 to 5, Name this favorite GetXPATH2 (step4)

11)Repeat steps 6 and 7 for GetXPATH2 that you just created.

12)Enter the following in the URL field for GetXPATH2

```
javascript:function o__o(){var currentNode=document.selection.createRange().parentElement();var path=[];while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1)break;}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}var xpath="/"+path.reverse().join('/');clipboardData.setData("Text", xpath);}o__o();
```

13)Repeat Step 9.

You are all done!!

Now to get the XPATH of elements just select the element with your mouse. This would involve clicking the left mouse button just before the element (link, button, image, checkbox, text etc) begins and dragging it till the element ends. Once you do this first select the favorite GetXPATH1 from the favorites menu and then select the second favorite GetXPATH2. At this point you will get a confirmation, hit allow access button. Now open up a notepad file, right click and select paste option. This will give you the XPATH of the element you seek.

Comment: Tried this nothing happened, while dev tools is on, the GetXPATH2 generates an error `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference`. Tried again on another site and element and it worked, so seems dependent on you selecting it properly/the site you are trying to do it on. Could just be my settings?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not working on IE11. I have followed these exact steps. Can you help ?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference... Getting this error in ie 11