# How can I quickly check if a xpath is valid in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, selenium

I am evaluating using Selenium to perform automated testing of my company's Asp.net Webforms application.  Since most of the html ids are auto-generated I am trying to rely on xpaths to be able to interact with my page.

As I am knew to xpaths, I am having issues trying to pinpoint the exact xpath I need to click on this element.  The process of changing my coded xpath, compiling my C# app, loading the app, running the app, then having Selenium exception out is getting pretty annoying.  I need to find some way to quickly determine if an xpath is valid (i.e. exists) or not.

Unfortunately, they coded this site to only work in IE, so that is all i have access to.

If someone has a good quick way for me to test an xpath out in IE, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried using bookmarks? see here: http://www.testingdiaries.com/find-xpath-in-ie-browser/

Answer (score 1):

**Use the [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**.

This is a popular tool that through the years has taught XPath the fun way to thousands of developers.

You first load an XML file and then can enter any XPath expressions and see the selected nodes immediately hi-lighted in the XML document. There are many more features, even for experienced developers.

**The XPath Visualizer can be downloaded [here](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**.

Comment: How do I export the current page as xml?  Since the elements I am looking for are not on the page until some ajax happens, I cannot just export the View->Source

Comment: @KallDrexx: You need some browser tool for this, and this is not an XPath problem.

Comment: While true, this doesn't solve the issue I have presented in my original Question.  I need some way to take my page in IE and verify an Xpath will work with it.

Comment: @KallDrexx: The XPath Visualizer is an IE html page itself. This means, that the XPath expression is evaluated under IE. As for XML received via AJAX, you need to use a tool similar to a JS debugger so that you can break at the location when the AJAX response is received and then get the XML. Your original question is how to verify that an XPath expression selects the desired nodes from an XML document, not how to obtain that XML document. The latter isn't an XPath question at all.

Comment: The XML isn't received via ajax, the ajax is adding and removing elements from the DOM after actions.  Those new nodes are what I need to figure out the XPath for, and I can't find any way to export the post-ajax HTML in IE to use in a tool such as this.

Comment: @KallDrexx: If there isn't a good IE tool for this, you could probably use FF or another browser just for the debugging.

Comment: Can't unfortunately, this website doesn't work in any other browser but IE (and the company has no intentions of fixing it so it works in other browsers)

Comment: @KallDrexx: Then you need to use JS debugger that works with IE.

Comment: This tool doesn't do the job as asked; it only works on an existing static xml file, but the question is about how to verify xpaths in a dynamic web page.

Comment: @vincebowdren, I understand the question as having a tool that one can use to verify that a particular XPath expression (probably generated by another tool) is syntactically correct and is selecting the wanted nodes. The XPath Visualizer does exactly this. It can be used for testing, *before* a program is really deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This StackOverflow post has some links to techniques for finding XPath in IE.

[Finding an elements XPath using IE Developer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)

I particularly like this solution in that post: http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2008/12/xpath-in-internet-explorer.html

However, to test/verify your XPath, whether found from such tools or you defined it yourself, you may want to do something like this (if you're thinking something similar to what FirePath provides for XPath/CSS validity verification):

http://autumnator.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/testing-xpath-and-css-locators-firepath-style-across-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

> As I am knew to xpaths, I am having issues trying to pinpoint the
>   exact xpath I need to click on this element. The process of changing
>   my coded xpath, compiling my C# app, loading the app, running the app,
>   then having Selenium exception out is getting pretty annoying.

I've created [SWD Page Recorder](https://github.com/dzhariy/swd-recorder/releases) for this purpose. 
It can work with all browsers supported by Selenium WebDriver and allows to debug, test and save locators for further editing.

When you download Page Recorder, please, put the Internet Explorer driver near the executable: [IE Driver Download page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Do F12 on the IE browser and copy the html. Then open the notepad and paste the html and save it as .html file. Finally you got the html page, then you can open the saved file in Firefox fox browser for validating xpath with firebug or firepath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the with Fire-IEBrowser.xlsm a google project application,

This will help you to find XPath of web elements in IE

You can find this application [here](http://code.google.com/p/fire-ie-selenium/downloads/list)

Also, you can find the more better solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)

Answer (score 0):

You could use my little java project, The Browsermator, to run/check your routines first:  https://www.browsermator.com  It would save you the trouble of re-running builds all the time.