# How can I find the Xpath of an Element in IE 11 browser? Can you please explain me with full steps?

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath

How can I find the Xpath of an Element in IE 11 browser? Can you please explain me with full steps?

Comment: You can use the IE Developer tools (F12) and then form the xpath. Else see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool

Comment: Can u please tell me how do I form the xpath by using IE developer tool ? The solution provided in the above mentioned link is not working any more

Comment: I dont think IE has an Xpath engine. You will have to manually form the Xpath by looking at the element's attributes. Or try out IE debugbar.

Comment: Can you please tel me how do I manually form the Xpath by looking at the elements attribute?

Comment: See this - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

Comment: There is no such thing as "the XPath of an element". There are many different XPath expressions that will find a particular element. A lot depends on what you want to use the XPath expression for: if it's for diagnostics, then you are probably not too concerned about namespaces, but if you want to execute the XPath expression to retrieve the original element, then you need to think about (a) how to handle binding of namespace prefixes in the XPath expression, and (b) whether you want the XPath expression to be resilient to changes in the DOM tree before it is executed.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to automate a web application using Selenium in c#. I want to select the menu and then select submenu, for that I want the Xpath of both elements which is dynamic. Hence if I get the Xpath for them can automate it easily. Thats my concern