# Add-ons for IE to find xPath for Selenium Script

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, browser, automated-tests

I am new in StackOverFlow posting my first question to get the xPath for my Selenium script which is written for IE browser. I want to know any shortcut or add-ons is available for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool

Answer (score 0):

Please Launch your application in Mozilla Firefox to find xpaths. Because it has a really handy add-on to find xpath of a WebElement. Please use following steps:
Launch Firefox
go to tool->add-on-> search for add-on "Fire bug" 
add to Firefox and relaunch Firefox

Also add the add on FirePath and xpath checker as well.

This is a handy solutions for finding the xPaths.

The same you use in your code and launch using IE. It will work.