# How to write and execute xpath in IE browser

Tags: selenium, xpath

My application works in Internet Explorer and I want to write xpath to create selenium test suite.Please suggest how to write and execute xpath in IE browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding an elements XPath using IE Developer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Firebug which is an Add-on for Firefox. Firebug integrates with Firefox to put a wealth of web development tools at your fingertips while you browse. You can edit, debug, and monitor CSS, HTML, and JavaScript live in any web page.

You can also generate Xpath and use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted something for Internet Explorer browser directly. Do we have ??

Comment: xpath will be same in all the browsers. So, you can find xpath in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to achieve. XPath over downloaded HTML text, XPath over generated DOM in browser page, XPath over some XML taken either from XML island in browser page or from external source...

If you need to evaluate XPath on existing page this page should be treated as XHTML or XML document by IE. I.e. not any page has native support for XPath.

If the page is not xmlDocument you could read page dom and create clone XML.

Once you have XML then simplest is to use libs like xml4jquery or  AmdHarness-amd-xml and evaluate XPath in JavaScript.

If you need to run XPath on someone else's page the easiest way is to run JS by bookmarklet. Something like http://xmlaspect.org/XmlView . The bookmarklet gives the JS string as a function body to be run by Selenuim code.

LMN if the bookmarklet is the solution you are looking for, I will create one for XPath.

The selenium web driver allows to run script as well:

```
String title = (String)jse.executeScript(
    "return document.evaluate(xPath, node, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue");
```

But you still need the XML source and code for extracting the XPath results as string, array, NodeList where JS libraries at your service.