# How to evaluate or verify xpaths in IE for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I have a web application which is made to work ONLY for IE browser. I know it sounds weird, but that's client requirement. My actual problem is with developing test scripts using Selenium. Using IE's developer tools, i can design the XPATHs, but i dont know how to evaluate it.

There may be multiple nodes/elements which could match with my xpath. In chrome, it was easy with developer tools as Find works by String, selector or xpath. But i am going nuts in IE, because Find works ONLY by String or query selector (no xpath support).

I tried with [bookmarklets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)/[javascripts](http://www.testingdiaries.com/find-xpath-in-ie-browser/) etc., but not of much help as i did in Chrome, Any suggestions please?

Comment: I have also found an article regarding same. refer : http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/fire-ie-selenium-tool-ie-browser/

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. I haven't try and it looks it need microsoft office

Comment: I have updated my answer. It look lil effort but you can evaluate your XPath using same

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.

Go to Internet Explorer, Inspect and copy the whole body part.

Now go the below URL:

- http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi
- Paste the HTML in HTML BOX section.
- Select XPath 3.0 option
- Write your XPath and evaluate

[image]

OR save the body code in HTML file and open the file using chrome

**OR**

you can generate locators like xpath using below :

https://github.com/dzharii/swd-recorder/releases

- Download the zip file
- Now add the IEDriverServer.exe path in an environmental variable.
- Copy the IEDriverServer.exe file in swdPageRecorder folder as well.
- Open the SwdPageRecorder.exe
- Now in Browser Setting select Internet Explorer and click on start
- Now enter URL in Browser section and Now click on GO> button
- Now click on Locators tab in SwdPageRecorder
- click on start on "WebBrowser Element Explorer"
- Now go to page and click on ctrl + RightClick

It will show you all required locators

Tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4jnX0PF_mc