# Why is XPath not working in IE?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

I am trying to find an element using XPath. It works flawlessly on Chrome, but not so much on Internet Explorer.

On Chrome, it works fine, but when I try to run it for IE, I am getting the following error which says

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a**

What could be causing this? I've already fixed the most common IE errors like setting "protected mode" and also "zoom" functionality.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Clearly you are trying to use an absolute xpath which is brittle. Try to use logical xpath.

Comment: Just because an XPath works in one browser doesn't mean it is guaranteed to work in another. You need to see if the HTML layout changes a bit between the two browsers

Answer (score 1):

Because XPath engine embed in browser is implemented by each Browser vendor self and actually they have difference in implement.  For earier IE, like  6 and 7 is not embed XPath engine.  If you use XPath on a browser which not embed XPath engine, Selenium will use self XPath library to execute your XPath, the Selenuim Xpath library not implement all XPath functionality and also has difference with other browser's Xpath engine.

Back to your issue, you missed a salsh at the beginning, it should be

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a
```

Because `HTML` node is the root of HTML DOM tree, so you should put `/` at head to tell your xpath start from root node

Or you can omit html in xpath: `//body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a`

because it's a truthy `HTML` node is the root of HTML Dom tree on every kind of browser.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your xpath to a css.  Xpath can vary between browsers where as CSS-SELECTORS are often the same cross browser. So inspecting with chrome will not be a problem.

html > body > form > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > a

Also Xpaths and IE are known for their problems. If you must use xpath, read [Finding an elements XPath using IE Developer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is getting xpath using `firebug` and `firepath` addons of firefox and also by increasing load time i.e `Thread.sleep()` between the inspection of elements. The first idea which is suggested by me works for me atleast. Let me know in case of any concerns