# Is there any tool to find xpath in IE browser

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, xpath, browser

My application works in IE and I am looking for a tool which can help to locate the element in IE browser.

I have tried fire-IE-selenium, but It does not help as it returns the Microsoft Visual Basic error pop up "Run-time error -'91':

Object variable or with block variable not set". Can anyone please help with the solution of this error or suggest any other tool or method to find the X-path in IE browser.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding an elements XPath using IE Developer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool)

Comment: Try to refer this site and try to test that tool with IE may help to get Xpath. Ref: https://seleniumbytes.wordpress.com/2016/12/14/xpath-tool-for-ie-browser/

Comment: You don't want to use a tool to find the XPath. It will likely generate a very large, very brittle locator. Your best bet is to spend some time reading some guides, etc. like [XPath | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) and learn how to handcraft them. Better yet, use IDs and CSS selectors first and only when those don't work (like finding an element by text or complicated DOM traversal) use XPath. CSS selectors are faster, the syntax is simpler, and they are better supported across browsers.