# Copy full DomX path in IE 11 Dom Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I want to copy the full DomX Path from a certain element in IE11 Developer console. Within Chrome you can open up F12, right click the element and "copy full DomX path" but as far as I can see IE doesn't have this functionality. 
Is any of you aware of a way to copy the full path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can get this old one to work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953886/295783

Answer (score 0):

I think there's not such a way to copy the full xpath in IE Dom Explorer. I also tried the bookmartlet solution but it doesn't work.

You could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool/20882291#20882291) in the thread. To use [SWD Page Recoder](https://github.com/dzharii/swd-recorder/releases/tag/v3.13.0.2018.06.28) along with [IE web driver](https://selenium.dev/downloads/) to find the xpath of elements.