# Does X Path Function works on internet explorer via Blue Prism

Tags: html, xpath, blueprism

When i try to spy the browser element using X path on internet explorer using application modellor on Blue prism. It doesn't Works is there any way that X path works on explorer as on chrome and Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990225/finding-an-elements-xpath-using-ie-developer-tool

Answer (score 0):

XPath is not supported in Blue Prism integrations with Internet Explorer. This is all but confirmed by its absence from listing on the [*HTML Attributes* Blue Prism documentation page](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-10/en-us/attributes-html.htm?tocpath=Interface%7CStudio%7CObject%20studio%7CApplication%20modeller%7C_____8).

If you need this functionality, you must use one of either Chrome, Firefox, or Chromium-based Edge; the [*Web Attributes* set](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-10/en-us/attributes-webpage.htm?tocpath=Interface%7CStudio%7CObject%20studio%7CApplication%20modeller%7C_____9) these browsers expose do include element XPath values.