# Xpath generator for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, selenium

can some one suggest an xpath generator (free) for IE similar to 
xpather (http://xpath.alephzarro.com/) in firefox. I am trying to use selenium and the application i am working on opens only in IE.

Is there an xpath generator for IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is *almost* a duplicate of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214862/equivalent-of-firebugs-copy-xpath-in-internet-explorer) where @PhiLho supplies an excellent answer--he provides "source code" for creating two IE bookmarklets to get the XPath of most anything in IE with a couple clicks.

However, worth mentioning here is a very good blog entry at [Software Functional Test Automation](http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2008/12/xpath-in-internet-explorer.html) that walks you through how to implement PhiLho's solution if you are less familiar with bookmarklets.

Comment: Yes, the blog mentioned above is good and well

Answer (score 2):

I've used selector gadget a bunch and love it:

http://www.selectorgadget.com/

I just tried it in IE8 and it seemed to work for me... maybe give that a shot. Good luck!

Comment: The process found in the above url works well with IE 8 for me also. nice

Answer (score 1):

In IE You need to insatll Bookmarklets.

STEPS TO INSTAL BOOKMARKLETS

1)Open IE

2)Type about:blank in the address bar and hit enter

3)From Favorites main menu select--->Add favorites

4) In the Add a favorite popup window enter name GetXPATH1.

5)Click add button in the add a favorite popup window.

6)Open the Favorites menu and right click the newly added favorite and select properties 
option.

7)GetXPATH1 Properties will open up. Select the web Document Tab.

8)Enter the following in the URL field.

`javascript:function getNode(node){var nodeExpr=node.tagName;if(!nodeExpr)return null;if(node.id!=''){nodeExpr+="[@id='"+node.id+"']";return "/"+nodeExpr;}var rank=1;var ps=node.previousSibling;while(ps){if(ps.tagName==node.tagName){rank++;}ps=ps.previousSibling;}if(rank>1){nodeExpr+='['+rank+']';}else{var ns=node.nextSibling;while(ns){if(ns.tagName==node.tagName){nodeExpr+='[1]';break;}ns=ns.nextSibling;}}return nodeExpr;}`

9)Click Ok. Click YES on the popup alert.

10)Add another favorite by following steps 3 to 5, Name this favorite GetXPATH2 (step4)

11)Repeat steps 6 and 7 for GetXPATH2 that you just created.

12)Enter the following in the URL field for GetXPATH2

`javascript:function o__o(){var currentNode=document.selection.createRange().parentElement();var path=[];while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1)break;}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}var xpath="/"+path.reverse().join('/');clipboardData.setData("Text", xpath);}o__o();`

13)Repeat Step 9.

You are all done!!

Now to get the XPATH of elements just select the element with your mouse. This would involve clicking the left mouse button just before the element (link, button, image, checkbox, text etc) begins and dragging it till the element ends. Once you do this first select the favorite GetXPATH1 from the favorites menu and then select the second favorite GetXPATH2. At his point you will get a confirmation, hit allow access button. Now open up a notepad file, right click and select paste option. This will give you the XPATH of the element you seek.

Answer (score 0):

About the script to get IE xpath, it's wonderful. However, it's not as easy useful as Firebug on Firefox. About the script in IE, it's almost not possible to get submit button xpath or xpath inside a frame (such as a iframe).

Just wonder whether the new release of IE would have a good support of xpath.