# Create XPath from Element not working in IE 6 7 8

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

My function works in `IE9`, anything under version 9, cracks;

I use this to get the `XPath` of a known `DOM Element`;

Does anyone know a function that replaces mine ?

```
function createXPathFromElement(elm) {
    var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    for (segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
    {
        if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
            var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
            for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
            }; 
            if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                return segs.join('/'); 
            } else { 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
            } 
        } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
        } else { 
            for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++;
            }; 
            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
        }; 
    };
    return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214862/equivalent-of-firebugs-copy-xpath-in-internet-explorer) for a solution.

As far as why yours fails in early IE: [`hasAttribute` was not introduced until IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304121(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm not sure exactly why you're checking the entire DOM for a duplicate ID attribute, considering it's not valid to have more than one element with the same ID. But I understand that real-world HTML isn't always valid. That said, you should be able to just use `if (elm.id && elm.id.length)` to check for the presence of the id attribute. Ditto with `class`.

You'll also run into problems if you expect to use that XPath in early versions of IE, as I don't believe it is supported for HTML documents. I believe there are solutions out on the internet for that, so I'll leave that for you (or some other kinder soul) to discover.